# Conditionals on preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm using preg_replace for adding text below images.

[My regex](http://regexr.com/3c2t3) looks like:

```
/<img.+?>/i
```

It works as expected when the img tag is alone

```
<img src="image.jpg" /> Lorem ipsum
```

However when the image is contained on a link the text also gets wrapped within the link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="image.jpg" /> Lorem ipsum</a>
```

[Image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dROcN.jpg)

Which is the best method to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Dang this is tough... I'm going to double check and make sure I know what you want before I continue further. You want just the image code, so <img src="image.jpg" /> And nothign more or less to be matched right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out not being that hard after all. I believe this is the stuff you want:

```
/<img.+\.\w+".|\/>/i
```

The main thing I did was make the match stop once it gets to the end of the extension (.\w+) and also include the quotation mark at the end which explains the " after that part.  And then I added an OR so the /> part is included in the match, but not the other junk. I was going to try a lookaround for that part but realized that was harder than it needed to be!

Hope that helps!